# Show a Message in MVC using TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to show a message in asp.net mvc. for this, i create a partial view. name of this partial view is _feedback. in body of this partial view i write this codes.

```
@model MyProject.SharedTools.OperationStatus

@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.IsSuccess)
    {
        @:Model.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        @:Model.Message;
    }
}
```

i put this code in _layout file:

```
@Html.Partial("_feedback")
```

and when i want to see a message from controller, using this code:

```
 operationStatus = _provinceRepository.Save();
 if (operationStatus.IsSuccess)
 {
     TempData["OperationStatus"] = operationStatus;
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

but i give this error:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyProject.Models.ProvinceModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.SharedTools.OperationStatus'.**

Comment: you define OperationStatus model in View but in controller you try to pass ProvinceModel model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have passed the correct model that your partial is expecting:

```
@Html.Partial("_feedback", Model.SomePropertyOfTypeOperationStatus)
```

If you do not specify a model as second argument to the `Html.Partial` helper, then it will automatically pass the model of the current view (which in your case is of type `MyProject.Models.ProvinceModel`) and that's why you are getting the error : your partial expects a model of type `MyProject.SharedTools.OperationStatus`.

Also it is not quite clear where you are using the TempData value that you stored in your controller inside your partial. Maybe it should be something like this:

```
@model MyProject.SharedTools.OperationStatus

@if (Model != null)
{
    @TempData["OperationStatus"]
}
```

or didn't you just mean to display directly the value you stored in TempData in your partial without using a model?

```
@TempData["OperationStatus"]
```