# C# Razor Helper Method displays Page within Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

I have a Razor Contact Form I'm creating, and everything works correctly except displaying the "successful message". I am calling a helper method DisplayCompletionMessage(). In that I have a heading and paragraph. When this method is called the message is displayed, but it is like I am putting an entire new page within the page I am on. It's like I have two master pages, even though the method only displays a heading and paragraph.

```
if (!isPostBack)
{
    Session.Remove(ContactFormModel.SessionKey);
    @RenderForm(formModel)
}
else
{
    if (Session[ContactFormModel.SessionKey] != null)
    {
        @DisplayResubmissionError()
        return;
    }

    formModel = new ContactFormModel(Request.Form);
    var errors = formModel.Validate();

    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        @DisplayErrors(errors)
        @RenderForm(formModel)
    }
    else
    {
        @DisplayCompletionMessage(formModel)
        @SendContactEmail(formModel)
    }
}
```

[image]

```
@helper DisplayCompletionMessage(ContactFormModel formModel)
{
    <h3>Thank You</h3>

    <p>
        Thank you, @formModel.Name, your message has been successfully submitted!
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code please, most likely you are calling a view and not a partial view.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction I added the code I used to call the helper method, as well as the helper method code.

Comment: Is this code in your view?!?!?! ....

Comment: @SimonWhitehead it is actually in a Macro.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020549/1476249) to display your messages.

In your controller, you set the TempData after sending the email

```
.... //other code in your controller
....
TempData["successMsg"] = "Thank you, " + User.Name + ", your message has been successfully submitted!";
....
....
```

And on the view you check it if the TempData isn't null and display it

```
@if(TempData["successMsg"] != null)
{
    <h3>Thank you</h3>
    <p>
        TempData["successMsg"].ToString()
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Well this worked, but now I realize that the helper method wasn't causing the page within a page. I removed all code associated with the submit button, and I still get the reload and page inside the page. Could this be due to the method="POST" on the form?

Comment: Maybe your @SendContactEmail helper method is the culprit?